# posting status to wall but only developer account can post, not user

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to create an app which allow user to post status to their wall.
but when I use the developer account to post, it worked fine, I can see the status on the wall. but when I use other account , nothing happen.
I set the app to public in developer setting:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBFo8g2VqhdWTFPZDdGSnNsZFU/view?usp=sharing

what should I do now ? (sorry,I'm bad at English)

Comment: its because you don't have the permission to post on other wall, if you want to post you have to take permission from facebook or else you can create test user on facebook developer and then you can post on the walls of those test users

Comment: how can i take permission ?

Comment: They are providing samples with the sdk .
go to samples - > HelloFacebookSample . 
It has all the code for post status, post photo.

Comment: And for this you need `publish_actions` permission,

Comment: first work with test user, if it works fine then you can go to developer console and ask for permission..

Comment: @rushankshah I succeed in post with my developer account, so I think the problem is the setting in developer.facebook.com

Comment: @TheGreat004 I have Succeed with test user, what should i do next, can you post a picture to show me how to ask for the permission in facebook.developer ?

Comment: follow this link, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit

Comment: I got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Submit your app for review in Facebook developer console. After the app is successfully reviewed by Facebook other user will also be able to post on wall through the app.

Comment: is it there : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBFo8g2VqhddEZLc2Z2aHUyVFU/view?usp=sharing